# error MSB4057: The target "PreLinkEvent" does not exist in the project

Tags: c++

i want to mod an opensource game coded in c++ when i first opened it in vs 2012 it asked me to update it to work now everytime i try to build it i get this error 
"Error  1   error MSB4057: The target "PreLinkEvent" does not exist in the project. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets   1290    11  ocgcore"
i havent modified the code at all yet atm i just want to build the original code
the code its pointing to is this

```
  <Target Name="DoLibOutputFilesMatch" Condition="'@(Lib)' != ''">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_OutputFileFromLib Include="%(Lib.OutputFile)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <VCMessage Condition="'@(_OutputFileFromLib)' == ''" Code="MSB8012" Type="Warning" Arguments="TargetPath;$(TargetPath);Linker;;Link"/>
    <VCMessage Condition="'@(_OutputFileFromLib)' != '' and '%(_OutputFileFromLib.FullPath)' != '$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($(TargetPath)))'" Code="MSB8012" Type="Warning" Arguments="TargetPath;$(TargetPath);Library;%(_OutputFileFromLib.FullPath);Lib"/>
    <VCMessage Condition="'@(_OutputFileFromLib)' != '' and '%(_OutputFileFromLib.Extension)' != '$(TargetExt)'" Code="MSB8012" Type="Warning" Arguments="TargetExt;$(TargetExt);Library;%(_OutputFileFromLib.Extension);Lib"/>
    <VCMessage Condition="'@(_OutputFileFromLib)' != '' and '%(_OutputFileFromLib.Filename)' != '$(TargetName)'" Code="MSB8012" Type="Warning" Arguments="TargetName;$(TargetName);Library;%(_OutputFileFromLib.Filename);Lib"/>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is from MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/969f34e9-3c48-4262-a369-81f9b88ce3cd/error-msb4057-the-target-endtoenditeration-does-not-exist-in-the-project?forum=tfsbuild

Seems like you're using a team build script with an unknown target on your machine.

This means that you did not define PreLinkEvent build target in the script.

Maybe the game you downloaded used a team build (probably if it had more than 1 developer) and thus you are using their team build which is not suitable for your machine, without making some changes to the build environment.

Comment: the thing is it built fine in vs2010 only after updating to2012 do i get this error